# Generate all permutations: Why is the yielded value in recursion not in the output?

Tags: python, iteration, generator

I came across a [problem](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa21/hw/hw05/#q1-generate-permutations) in CS61A:

> Given a sequence of unique elements, a permutation of the sequence is a list containing the elements of the sequence in some arbitrary order. For example, `[2, 1, 3]`, `[1, 3, 2]`, and `[3, 2, 1]` are some of the permutations of the sequence `1, 2, 3]`.
>
> Implement `gen_perms`, a generator function that takes in a sequence `seq` and returns a generator that yields all permutations of `seq`. For this question, assume that `seq` will not be empty.
>
> Permutations may be yielded in any order.

My solution to this is:

```
def gen_perms(seq):
    def generator(seq_):
        list_seq=list(seq_)
        if len(list_seq)==1:
            yield list_seq
        else:
            for item in generator(list_seq[1:]):
                for i in range(len(list_seq)):
                    yield item[:i]+[list_seq[0]]+item[i:]
    return generator(seq)
```

An example call:

```
print(list(gene_perms([1, 2, 3])))
```

The above code outputs the expected result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

My doubt is that it looks like it should not have had the correct output. In my code `generator` is built recursively and the `yield` line of `generator(list_seq[1:])` occurs ahead of that of `generator(list_seq)` and it should yield the permutation of its subsequence first, and only then the permutation of the sequence itself. But the former didn't even appear in the output.

Could someone explain this to me? Maybe I have a wrong comprehension about how generators work.

Comment: You can compare your code with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) (the "roughly equivalent to" part).

Comment: You have defined `list_seq` before, so using `list_seq[1:]` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You probably want to check for `len(list_seq) == 0` next to `... == 1`. The current code might work out fine for an empty list, but it would be clearer with this check and an early return.

Comment: *"`generator(list_seq[1:])` is called ahead of `generator(list_seq)`"*: this is not true. Please clarify why you think that? Surely it is a necessary requirement that `generator(list_seq)` is called before `generator(list_seq[1:])` could be called.

Comment: @trincot I think the principle for generators is that it yields values in the order of when the corresponding `yield` statement appears. Thus the permutation of the subsequence of the sequence passed in should occur first. But it isn't even in the output.

Comment: OK, so you are not talking about the *calls*, but the *yields*. But not everything that is yielded is yielded to the top-level caller. It is only yielded to the execution context that made the recursive call -- so to the code that *consumes* it: the `for` loop. This yielded value is never bubbled upwards the recursion tree or something like that. So the top level caller only sees the yields that were made by the `for` loop of the initial (top-level) execution of the function.

Comment: @9769953 Good advice. But that may be not the point of my problem cause  maybe I didn't clarify this clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `yield` of the deeper recursive calls happen *earlier*, these yielded values are *consumed* by the `for` loop that made that deeper recursive call. These yielded values do not magically bubble up the whole recursion tree! They are consumed by the immediate caller, not by any of the callers that are higher-up the recursion stack.

Each generator execution is the (only) responsible for yielding values to their immediate consumer. The deeper calls in recursion do not produce the values that the top-level caller will see.

### Other remarks on your code

Unrelated to your question, but:

- Your code would enter into infinite recursion if it would get an empty list as input. To avoid that, make that the base case of your recursion.
- You should not explicitly yield *lists* in your code; don't create lists with `list(seq_)` nor with `[seq[0]]`, because:

  - If the input sequence is a string, you don't want to produce lists as permutations of it, but strings. Instead, in your `yield`, take a slice also for injecting the first element, so not `[seq[0]]` (which creates a list), but `seq[:1]`: this works well for strings and tuples too.
  - Sequences have support for all the operations you perform on them (notably, [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common))
  - If you're worried about mutations of the original input: none of your code *mutates* any of the produced permutations. Also, if the top-level caller would be so unwise to mutate a list they got from this process, it will not negatively affect the process. The reason is that the `yield` you do in the loop, already creates a new sequence (by the use of slicing and the `+` operator).
- As your inner function has the same signature (parameter and return type) as the outer function, you don't need the inner function: just call `gen_perms` recursively.

Taking those points into account, your function could be:

```
def gen_perms(seq):
    if not seq:
        yield seq
    else:
        for item in gen_perms(seq[1:]):
            for i in range(len(seq)):
                yield item[:i] + seq[:1] + item[i:]
```

#### Example runs

```
print(*gen_perms([1,2,3]))  # list input
# -> [1, 2, 3] [2, 1, 3] [2, 3, 1] [1, 3, 2] [3, 1, 2] [3, 2, 1]
print(*gen_perms((1,2,3)))  # tuple input
# -> (1, 2, 3) (2, 1, 3) (2, 3, 1) (1, 3, 2) (3, 1, 2) (3, 2, 1)
print(*gen_perms("abc"))    # string input
# -> abc bac bca acb cab cba
```

(Admittedly, the input should not be a `range` instance, as the output cannot have "permuted" ranges; there is no such thing. I would assume the code challenge does not intend to call this function with range objects)

Comment: My intention for producing a `list` version of `seq_` is that we could apply the code for any iterable data type, not just list. I'm not sure if the slicing operation could be implemented on any iterable. If it is, this line of list producing is surely redundant.

Comment: The reason for not having the base case of empty input is that an assumption for the code of the course CS61A is we never receive empty input, for convenience maybe.

Comment: As to your first comment: the code challenge says that the input is a *sequence*. [A sequence has support for slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common).

Comment: There is also another reason why you should not call `list`: if the input sequence is a string, I would assume the generator should not yield lists of characters, but strings.